# Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot use "ref" after the widget was disposed : flutter riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

`my problem is when i pop this screen then come back , i can't access to ref.read and and exception Bad state: Cannot use "ref" after the widget was disposed

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:learn_with_lina/providers/messages_provider.dart';

class _CallScreenState extends ConsumerState<CallScreen> {

void initState() {
  print("start call Screen");
  super.initState();
  initSpeechToText();
}

  MessageModel addMessageToList(
    {required String text, required bool received, required bool isLoading}) {
   final messageModel =
     MessageModel(text: text, received: received, isLoading: isLoading);

   ref.read(messagesProvider.notifier).addMessage(messageModel);

   return messageModel;
  }

  void updateMessageInList(
   {required MessageModel messageModel,
   required String text,
   required bool isLoading,
   required bool error}) {
  ref
     .read(messagesProvider.notifier)
    .updateMessage(messageModel, text, isLoading, error);
  }

  void sendMessage(String text) async {
   if (!mounted) return;
    // add the message of user to the list of messages
   addMessageToList(text: text, received: false, isLoading: false);
   setState(() {
   isLoadingSendMessage = true;
  });

  // get old messages
   final oldMessages = ref.read(messagesProvider);
  // add Loader to the List view
  final assistantMessage = addMessageToList(
    text: '', received: true, isLoading: isLoadingSendMessage);
   // call chat gpt
   final answer = await ChatGptApi.getChatGptAnswer(text, oldMessages);
   setState(() {
   isLoadingSendMessage = false;
   });
   if (answer.trim().isNotEmpty) {
    bool error = false;
    if (answer.trim() == 'An internal error occurred') {
     error = true;
   }
    updateMessageInList(
      messageModel: assistantMessage,
      text: answer.trim(),
      isLoading: isLoadingSendMessage,
      error: error);
    systemSpeak(answer);
  }
 }
```

i tried to check if(!mounted) but in this cas the mounted value is always false after comme back to this screen

Comment: In which line did the error happen? Also where is the definition of `initSpeechToText` method? Does it have a `ref.read` call too?

Comment: in sendMessage Method iside it im calling the provider and ref ..

Answer (score 0):

> i tried to check if(!mounted) but in this cas the mounted value is
> always false after comme back to this screen

That makes sense, you popped the route and come back pushing it again, so the previous one is not mounted anymore. This seems more a problem of understanding the lifecycle of the widgets and widget tree more than Riverpod but if you really insist of using that callback method after being disposed you could just save a reference to your provider as a variable and use it:

```
class _CallScreenState extends ConsumerState<CallScreen> {
late MessageProvider messageP; ///<---- use this reference in your methods

void initState() {
  print("start call Screen");
  super.initState();
  initSpeechToText();
  messageP = ref.read(messagesProvider.notifier);
}

  MessageModel addMessageToList(
    {required String text, required bool received, required bool isLoading}) {...
  }

  void updateMessageInList(
   {required MessageModel messageModel,
   required String text,
   required bool isLoading,
   required bool error}) {...
  }

  void sendMessage(String text) async {...
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
     messageP = ref.read(messagesProvider.notifier);
 }
```

Still take this with cautios, and try to cahnge your logic inside your provider (which seems more logical) so you can send messages even when your widget is disposed

Comment: can i distroy all the widget after leave it the when i come back i ceate new one ??

Comment: that's basically what you're doing, pop and push destroy and create a new one

Answer (score 0):

If you have a call to `ref` inside `initSpeechToText`, then you can't call it directly in the `initState`. You have to put it inside this callback:

```dart
void initState() {
  // ...

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    initSpeechToText();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give you my help, but I have not so clear your code....

...but anyway , here what I can say:

the rules are:

1. in the **init/destroy** method you must use

   ref.**read**(...) // and never **setState**(....)
2. In every **callback** (**onButtonPressed**(...), ....etc...) you should use:

   ref.**read**(...) // and also **setState**(...)
3. In the **`build(BuildContext context)`** method call

   ref.**watch**(...) // and never **setState**(...)
4. Finally, if the problem was the

   **setState**(...)

Consider not to use **setState**(...): your are using Riverpod !!!

It can/must simplify your code.
Thus, forget setState(...), Riverpod will do it for your (give a try to **ConsumerWidget** over **ConsumerStatefulWidget**).

I tend to use ConsumerStatefulWidget only if I have some animations....

Moreover in the callbacks I use

```
ref.read(...)
```

because in the callbacks I do not ask for the state, but I call the **notifier** , and the notifier would change its internal state.

Moreover using  ref.watch(...) in the build(...) method would "**dirt**" the widget and force Flutter to repaint it.

What I mean is that:

in a callback, you simply write something like:

```
void _myCallBack(...) {
    ....
    var notifier = ref.read(myStateProvider.notifier)
    notifier.doMyStuff(....);
    ...
}
```

In the Notifier:

```
@riverpod
class MyState extends _$MyState {
    @override
    MyViewModel build() {... }
    
    void doMyStuff(...) {
        ....
        state = ... ;
    }
}
```

While in the build(...) method:

```
Widget build(... ) {
    var myState = ref.watch(myStateProvider);
    ...
    ...
}
```

That would mark as **dirty** the widget, thus flutter would repaint it.
Note I 've never use the **setState**(...) method anywhere, it was not needed.

hope it would help you.